# Scanner in a function. Closing the Scanner is causing trouble

Tags: java, oop

> I am getting flickering screen when closing the scanner,but without closing it works fine.

```
public void removeBranch() {
        try {
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter branch id to remove:");
            int Id=input.nextInt();
            int toDelete=branchPresent(Id);
            if(toDelete!=-1) {
                branches.remove(toDelete);
                System.out.println("Branch removed");
            }else {
                System.out.println("\n No such Branch!\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nsomething went wrong while removing  !\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Closing that `Scanner` will also close `System.in`; better to construct your `Scanner` outside the function and pass it to your function.

Comment: *Closing the Scanner is causing trouble* - once you close `System.in` you can not reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Close the scanner in `finally` block

```
try{
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
// Do stuff
}
catch {
// Handle exception
}
finally {
input.close();
}
```